# How to set default color for MUI components in theme color pallete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes, color-palette

I am wondering if someone knows if it is possible to set default color for MUI components like Checkbox, TextField.
Right now, they automatically use primary color, but i would like to set Checkbox to secondary and TextField to terciary (custom color). So my question is: Is it possible to set default color for these components in theme color pallete?

I tried to use different colors but always end up with components using primary color. I expect that i can override somehow this color and set my own color for whole component like checkbox etc.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can do that! MUI is pretty great in offering a lot of different ways to customize their components.

For your `Checkbox` component you have a few options. You could use MUI's `color` prop which takes a keyword from their color palette, ie `primary`, `secondary`, `danger`. The available colors can be found [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button/#:%7E:text=%27inherit%27%0A%7C%C2%A0%27primary%27%0A%7C%C2%A0%27secondary%27%0A%7C%C2%A0%27success%27%0A%7C%C2%A0%27error%27%0A%7C%C2%A0%27info%27%0A%7C%C2%A0%27warning%27%0A%7C%C2%A0string)

```
<Checkbox {...label} defaultChecked color="secondary" />
```

Or you could pass in their `sx` prop, which is the same as using the `style` props to pass inline CSS.

```
<Checkbox
  checked={checked}
  onChange={handleChange}
  sx={{
    color: "red",
    '&.Mui-checked': {
      color: "red",
    },
  }}
  inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }}
/>
```

In the `sx` prop you would just need to identify the class you want to target.

The third option is creating your own custom theme, information can be found [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/). With this you could also customize the components you're using, but again you would just need to figure out what class or component you want to customize. But you could create a variety of different theme options that you can then access throughout your entire app.

```
//create your theme here, 
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#757ce8',
      main: '#3f50b5',
      dark: '#002884',
      contrastText: '#fff',
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#ff7961',
      main: '#f44336',
      dark: '#ba000d',
      contrastText: '#000',
    },
  },
});

// wrap the component you're wanting to access the them, can be a specific component
// or your whole app

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <CustomCheckbox defaultChecked />
</ThemeProvider>

//customize components so when you use them they default to your settings

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiButtonBase: {
      defaultProps: {
       // The props to change the default for.
       disableRipple: true, // No more ripple, on the whole application !
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer. So can I set default color to defaultProps settings of component like on the last screen? So lets say I want to set secondary palette color as default color for MuiButtonBase. Do I understand it correctly that after this change the button will use secondary as its color?

Comment: Yep, exactly! If that ends up working for you, do you mind marking it as an answer? It'll allow me to respond to more people.